# Is it possible to write a functor instance for this type?

Tags: haskell, functor

Given:

```
data MyType a = Done a | Out a (MyType a) | In (a -> MyType a)
```

I'm struggling to implement `fmap f (In x)`. My initial thought was `In $ \y -> fmap f (x y)` but that doesn't work since `x` operates on a `MyType a` - it's like I need someway to fmap over both the argument as well as the stuff "inside", if that makes sense. I guess what I'm looking for is a way to create `b -> m b`  from `a -> m a` given an `a -> b` - is that possible?

Comment: No, if you let Haskell derive the functor automatically, it raises an error: "*Constructor ‘In’ must not use the type variable in a function argument*".

Comment: If you `fmap`, you are given a function `a -> b`, not a function `b -> a`, so you can not "convert back". Unless of course you use a (rather) nonsensical implementation (by passing  `undefined` as parameter, etc.), but that will likely raise other problems, making it break the functor laws.

Comment: Your second comments makes a lot of sense. I had the feeling it wasn't possible but not the reasoning.

Comment: In general, if you have a ADT like `data MyType a b = MyConstructor (a  -> b)`, then `MyType` is _covariant_ in argument `b`  and _contravariant_ in argument `a` (depending on which side of the arrow each argument is). _Covariants functors_ are regular haskell functors, whereas _contravariant functors_ can be instantiate to `Contravariant` type class. If your data is both, you can make an instance of  `Profunctor` type class

Comment: Btw, _profunctors_ are defined for two paramaters types. So, AFAIK, you should modify your data type if you go in this direction

Answer (score 5):

I suspect the type you *actually* want is this one (or some specialization where you have chosen a specific `i`):

```
data MyType i o = Done o | Out o (MyType i o) | In (i -> MyType i o)
```

The primary difference here is that the `In` constructor uses separate types for the argument and result of the function it contains. You should find the `Functor` instance much easier to write once you have separated the input and output parameters like this.